# Missing margin around "post your answer" button

Tags: bug, status-review, design

When I'm not logged into my SO account, under the "Your Answer" field, I see the post your answer button, along with some text to the left of it (I'm not using an RTL layout) that has no margins. Not sure if the text or the button is the one that's supposed to have margins, but it looks not very professional (to say the least).

Here's a screenshot of what I see:
[image: Screenshot of the probmlem]
I'm using Edge Dev version 115.0.1866.1 for x-64 systems and running a Windows 11 laptop.

Comment: Can confirm that I see the same in Google Chrome (Version 113.0.5672.127) on Windows 11. The button looks weird: why is there a linebreak in it? Compare it to how the button looks here on meta. Also the text looks like it should be below the button, not next to it.

Comment: I also repro in Chrome, even under Windows 7. So, this isn't something that just affects bleeding-edge browsers. It *might* be an intentional design decision (hard to imagine), but it's definitely different from what it looks like for logged-in users, and so definitely merits the status of "bug" in my estimation. I've escalated it for staff to review.

Comment: @CodyGray "hard to imagine"? With their track record, I wouldn't be surprised to soon see "We've graduated improved answer button experience. Our measurements indicate 27.39% increase in CTR." :P

Comment: I find most of their track record difficult to imagine. Even to believe. @Dan